# Nodejs Envioment variable Fedora

Tags: node.js, fedora

I'm trying to do someting with nodejs and I got this error

```
 /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I now this error is for nodejs its called on fedora the same way 'nodejs' my question is how can I Change that just for 'node' ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you can run it via command `nodejs`?

Comment: there are a lot of packages that running with node so when that happens a got a error :S

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure nodejs is installed? It looks like it's a script or shell trying to launch node but not finding the executable in your path.

Try running "node --version" from a terminal, does that work?

If not, make sure you have nodejs installed. Instructions for Fedora can be found here https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

> sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/fedora/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
>
> sudo yum install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm